# QGIS edit stuck on drawing hexagons. How to reset editing settings to default?

Tags: qgis, editing

I am trying to draw a polygon but QGIS forces me to draw hexagons, squares or everything on the shape digitising tool bar. Please look at the following 2 screenshots.

[image]

I understand that I must toggle the toolbars but it seems like there is no way to switch to the default drawing. I have right-clicked the taskbar, but it shows the available toolbar. I browsed the options on both toolbars, but there is no regular polygon. how do I set the editing bit to draw regular polygon?

[image]

This is the live action on the clicking.

[image]

Comment: witch QGIS version are you using ? on mine (3.28.2) between the "save layer edit" icon and the "Add polygon feature" there is another icon with a drop-down list to choose to use segment, curve or regular shape...

Comment: Maybe you just need to give more space on the bottom row of toolbar, try to undock the digitizing toolbar to see if the missing icon appear...

Comment: @J.R thanks, but sadly no, I dragged them off, so the toolbars are floating.

Comment: @J.R sorry, I am using 3.26.0 - I just discovered that this is indeed a bug. I checked with 3.22.0 and I know what's wrong. I'm writing the answer

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug in v 3.26.0. In version 3.22 LTR, this is how it is supposed to look

[image]

In v 3.26 (the buggy version) the activate editing tool does not activate the shape digitising toolbar.

[image]

solution: avoid 3.26. use 3.22 or 3.28.

Comment: This is not a bug. There was a change made regarding editing modes (segment, shape, etc.) between 3.22 and 3.26. The button to switch modes is on a separate toolbar. In 3.28, that button was relocated to a more convenient location. I disagree with how that change was implemented though and I have raised an issue in the tracker a few weeks ago.

Comment: @Gabriel, thanks for the clarification; this "separate" toolbar is what I am looking for. Which toolbar is it?

Comment: Check this issue: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/49541 There is a screen capture that shows the button and its location on a toolbar. The button has been moved to the main feature edit toolbar.